# Генерируется bash.exe.stackdump в папке при запуске git bash

Tags: git, git-bash, git-cmd

Генерируется bash.exe.stackdump в рабочей папке при запуске git bash из контекстного меню. Система — windows7 x64, Git Bash — последний доступный релиз git-2.17.0-64-bit.  Для чего он генерируется? Что нужно сделать чтобы он больше не появлялся? Содержимое файла:

```
Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=000772FBF37
rax=0000000000001250 rbx=00000000FFFF8F70 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000180010018 rsi=00000001802772E0 rdi=0000000180222490
r8 =0000000000372230 r9 =00000001802772E0 r10=00000000FFFF7000
r11=00000000FFE032F0 r12=00000000FFFF8E50 r13=0000000180222490
r14=00000000FFFF8DF0 r15=00000000FFFF8F78
rbp=0000000000000420 rsp=00000000FFFF8CB8
program=C:\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe, pid 1560, thread 
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```

Comment: Обновить git bash.

Comment: Latest source Release git-2.17.0-64-bit  вчера переустанавливал.